# Unable to use header files which are located in different directory

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to use Z-compression library in Android. So far I've set up the Android Studio with NDK and the sample project is working butter smooth. And Once I added the C files to the JNI folder, few header files are located in various sub folders, and Android Studio is unable to include those header file and it says: `cannot find 'xxxxx.h'`

There are previous answers to the same question, however many are obsolete and outdated. I am using Android Studio 2.1.3 and here is the `build.gradle` file of my app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = 'com.example.hellojni'
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 4
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
        /*
         * native build settings: taking default for almost everything
         */
        ndk {
            moduleName = 'hello-jni'
            toolchain = 'clang'
            stl "stlport_shared"
            CFlags.addAll(['-Wall'])
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
            // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
            // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
            create("arm") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            }
            create("arm7") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
            create("arm8") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            }
            create("x86") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
            }
            create("x86-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
            }
            create("mips") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
            }
            create("mips-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
            }
            // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
            create("all")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried :

- Including `cFlags += "-I" + file("src/main/jni/").absolutePath`
- adding `stl "stlport_shared"` in gradle

based on other answers, however none did fix the problem. If anyone has resolved the same error before, kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a folder called Project, and it contains two folders with similarly-named headers foo/foo.h and bar/bar.h. Foo wants to `#include` bar.h, but it can't do that in it's current file scope. It has to go one directory behind to Project. To do that, the universal symbol `..` can be used:

```c++
#include "../bar/bar.h"
```

Moral of the story: Folder names are perfectly sane in a `#include` statement.